# How to use FFT algorithm to multiply to positive integers in base 2?

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, fast-fourier-transform

> We're given two positive integers of length $n$ in binary representation.
>
> Design an algorithm which divides the numbers into ${n \over k}$ blocks of size $k=\lg n$ using FFT algorithm.
>
> We can suppose that the multiplications that occur during recursive calls do not increase the length of the resulting numbers (not necessarily true in reality but can be supposed for the sake of the algorithm) therefore the multiplications can be performed in $\Theta(k^2)$ bit operations.

This is the solution of the algorithm I came across and I have some clarifications below:

1) Because we're given numbers in base $2$ then we can represent number $x$ such that $$x=2^0\cdot x_0+2^{k-1}\cdot x_1+...+2^{{kn \over k}-1}\cdot x_{{n \over k}-1}$$
where $x_i$ such that $i:0,1,2,..., {{n \over k}-1}$.

2) Now we can apply FFT (on ${2n \over k}$ roots of unity) to the vectors:
$$z = \operatorname{FFT}(\{x_0,x_1,..., x_{{n \over k}-1}\})\cdot \operatorname{FFT}(\{y_0,y_1,..., y_{{n \over k}-1}\})$$
$z$ being the resulting vector.

3) We apply inverse FFT on $z$ and assign the result the vector $r$.

4) The run time complexity of the steps 3 and 4 is $O\big({n \over k}\lg{n \over k}\big)$. Because the internal bit multiplications can be performed in $\Theta(k^2)$ then overall we have $O\big({k^2\cdot n \over k}\lg{n \over k}\big)$ = $O(nk(\lg n-\lg k))$

5) Lastly we need to do the sum in order to get the final result:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{{2n} \over k} r_i\cdot 2^i
$$
We'll perform the summation recursively dividing the input in half each time.

6) Because there're in step 5 there're ${n \over k\cdot 2^i}$ pairs and the size of each pair is $k\cdot 2^i$, the run time complexity of step 5 is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lg{n \over k}} k\cdot 2^i\cdot {n \over k\cdot 2^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{\lg{n \over k}} n=O(n(\lg n-\lg k))
$$
7) total run time complexity is 
$$O(n(\lg n-\lg k)+nk(\lg n-\lg k))=O(n\lg n(\lg n-\lg\lg n))$$

---

**Clarifications:**

- step 1): why are the coefficients  $2^0, 2^{k-1}, ..., 2^{{kn \over k}-1}$ and not $2^0, 2^1, 2^2,..., 2^{{n \over k}-1}$?
- step 6): I don't understand how we get to the first summation.
- step 7) I didn't understand the transition completely.

Comment: I don't know if I can explain the proof to you but it is basically the convolution theorem of Fourier transforms combined with the fact that multiplication is a convolution on the vector of digits (in any basis of digits).

Comment: @mathreadler I undestand the use of FFT and the convolutions analogy but  rather I don't understand the questions at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Multiplication of integers in binary representation is a convolution followed by propagation, ie. $11 \ast 11 = 121 = 201 = 1001$ @mathreadler

Comment: @reuns that is only because we usually strive to enforce the unique representation property of the position based number systems. The value remains the same even if we don't.

Comment: And can we do the propagation in the same time as the FFT algorithm, to avoid allocating $N^2$ bits to multiply two integers of $N$ bits ? @mathreadler

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you need $N^2$ bits?

Comment: @mathreadler can you at least offer some insight into step 6?

Comment: I would not be too good at explaining, I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you implemented the algorithm yet?

Comment: @Somos Not in pseudo code, but I described it in the OP

Comment: In step 1 "divides the numbers into n/k blocks of size k" means each block is of size $k$. Thus the coefficients should be $2^0,2^k,2^{2k},\dots$.

Comment: @Somos shouldn't then the coefficients in step 5 and 6 also be $2^0,2^k, 2^{2k}$?

Comment: Try it and see.